# POWEI BI | CASE WHEN / If condition for text string classification

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, powerquery

I would like to create a calculated dimension. How it should works is extract data from a column based on different condition, i was looking at the formulation in equivalent to the following:

In SQL:

```
CASE WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Data Field A,"((?i).*PMP).*")  
THEN "PMP Deal"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Data Field A,"((?i).*Native Display).*")  
THEN "PMP Dea"
ELSE "Non Standard Formats" END
```

In English:

If Data Field A contains text string PMP, please return results in column A as PMP Deal. 
If Data Field A contains text string Native Display, pleas return results in column A as Native Display.

Comment: From what I can tell a simple if statement will do what you require, assuming your data is column B starting in B1,  then use the formula in cell A1 =if(B1="PMP","PMP Deal",if(B1="Native Display",B1,"No Match") then fill the column A with the formula by dragging down the auto fill box, found on the right hand bottom corner of cell A1

Comment: are you looking for an answer in [tag:powerbi]?

Comment: Are you trying to write this like a DAX measure or calculated column?